# Jquery Validate - Marcar pelo menos 1 checkbox true

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

Eu uso bootstrap toogle desse exemplo: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Tenho 4 checkbox, uma delas devem ficar com true.

Como fazer isso com jquery validate ?

Segue código:

```
<label for="checkbox[]" generated="true"></label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox1" class="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox2" class="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox3" class="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox4" class="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>
```

Javasxcript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myform").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        rules: {
            "checkbox[]": { required: true, minlength: 1 }
        },
                       messages: {
            "checkbox[]": "<span style=\"color: #a94442;\">Uma das opções abaixo devem ser marcada *</span>"
        },
        ....
        ....
        ....        
    }   
}
```

Não acontece nada. Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Eu acho que é o nome da classe, tenta mudar, para não ficar com "[ ]"

Comment: Sim, tenta lá Matheus

Comment: @Miguel, não funcionou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é uma solução sem o plugin validate. Checar pelo menos um, tive de mudar o nome da classe dos inputs porque me estava a dar um erro.

> unrecognized expression: .checkbox[]:checked

Mudei para `checkbox`

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('.checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
      return;
  }
  alert('check em pelo menos um');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label for="checkbox[]" generated="true"></label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input id="checkbox4" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-onstyle = "success" data-offstyle = "danger" data-on = "Sim" data-off = "Não" data-size = "mini">
</label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: O que faz `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda faz com que o formulário não seja submetido antes das verificações/validações